# Amazon EMR job with many json files as input

Tags: python, json, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am writing a hadoop streaming application in python to run on EMR. The input for the EMR job is a directory of files in an S3 bucket, each of which is a json file containing a single json object. I would like the mapper to operate on each json file, one at a time, and produce a (key, value) pair like so:

Map:

> {'name':'foo', 'request':'bar'} -> ('name', {'request':'bar'})

Reduce:

> ('name', [{'request':'bar'}, {'request':'baz'}]) -> {'name':'foo', 'request':['bar', 'baz']}

It seems that this is doable if all of the json objects I would like to process are written as a single line in a file, though this is not the case; there are multiple newline characters in each .json file. Is there an input format tailored for such an operation? Please offer me some uidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WholeFileReader in Java:
https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch07/src/main/java/WholeFileInputFormat.java .

The key is that it returns false for isSplitable